# To determine if all datastructure's elements are true in Matlab

Tags: matlab, data-structures

Assume you have a data structure which can be "NxMx...xY". 
You cannot use the standard matrix operations directly.

Assume you need to verify only that if each element is "1" in each cell. 
So test if this datastructure is unitary. 
Assume that the datastructure is for instance 777x666x555.

Pseudocode

```
assert( isUnitary( signal ) );
```

**How can you verify that if each element is one?** 
Return 1 if all 1. Else 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious way to do this:

```
all(signal(:) == 1)
```